# Como redirecionar um usuário para uma página específica apenas no primeiro login do site em wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, login

Eu inclui direto na tabela wp_users alguns usuários, somente com o ID, USER_LOGIN, USER_PASS, USER_NICENAME E DISPLAY_NAME.

Ficando assim , por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO wp_users (ID, user_login, user_pass, user_nicename, user_email, 
user_url, user_registered, user_activation_key, user_status, display_name) 
VALUES
(1500, ‘steoliv’, ‘65442334hio’,’steoliv’, ”, ”,’2018-01-09 13:01:00′, ”, 0, 
‘Stefany’);
```

Eu gostaria que no primeiro acesso, feito pelo nome de usuário e senha que eu criei, redirecionasse o usuário para uma página , que eu tbm já criei (site/editar-cadastro) e atualizasse os dados com as informações que faltam, como por exemplo o e-mail.
Tem algum plugin ou algum código que seja possível fazer o que eu desejo?

Comment: acredito que você precise de uma `flag` para saber isso; tente adicionar outro campo como `first_login` no usuario e assim voce pode verificar se é ou não o primeiro login; quando realizar o cadastro o campo fica como "1" e depois de ir editar os dados na pagina que voce quer fique como "0".

Comment: Ta, mas ai vc está me dizendo para verificar.
Preciso de algo que me ajude nem que seja para fazer isso todas a vezes que o usuário logar. Se eu encontrar um que já faça isso já é meio caminho andado.

Answer (score -1):

Você pode utilizar uma **flag** para saber se é ou não a primeira vez que um usuário faz login na sua plataforma. Acrescente essa flag no seu banco de dados e sempre que o usuário for fazer login você testa a **fleg**. Depois de testar se o usuário e a senha estão corretos você testa a **flag**

```
if(result['flag'] == 0){
    // Atualiza a colona da flag
    $query = "UPDATE wp_users SET flag = 1 WHERE usuario = $usuario";
    mysqli_query($con,$query);
    // Faz o redirecionamento para a página de editar cadastro
    header("location: http://minhaurl/site/editar-cadastro");
}else{
    header("location: http://minhaurl/site/outra-area");
}
```